# phonegap facebook plugins don't logout properly

Tags: android, facebook, cordova

After several hours, a lot of reading, experiments and builds, I finally managed to log IN on my demo facebook app. Now I'm in front of what seems even bigger problem. I can't log OUT properly.

I tried 2 facebook plugins for phonegap and their result is absolutely the same:

[cordova-plugin-facebook4](https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4)

[phonegap-facebook-plugin](https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin)

To reproduce, first I'm going on my personal facebook profile/settings/apps/Apps Logged in with facebook and I'm removing the app that I'm experimenting with. In my case It's called DemoApp.

Than I'm executing the following code in my mobile application:

```
function logInOutTest() {
    alert('start login status check');
    facebookConnectPlugin.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(response));
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            alert('start log OUT');
            facebookConnectPlugin.logout(function () {
                alert('log out called');
            }, function(error) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(error));
            });
        }
        else {
            alert('start log IN');
            facebookConnectPlugin.login(["public_profile"],
                function (userData) {
                    alert("UserInfo: " + JSON.stringify(userData));
                },
                function (error) {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(error));
                }
            );
        }
    }, function (error) {
         alert('error: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
    });
}
```

**logInOutTest - 1st iteration log:**
*- start login status check
- { status : "unknown" }
- start log IN
- DemoApp screen explaining that it will receive my public profile. Continue
- UserInfo : { status : "connected, accessToken : valid }*

Here at this stage I'm already logged and DemoApp reappears in my Apps Logged in with Facebook

**logInOutTest - 2nd iteration log:**
*- start login status check
- { status : "connected", accessToken : still valid }
- start log OUT
- log out called*

log out called is in the success callback. Seems like I successfully logged out, but DemoApp is still in Apps Logged in with Facebook!!!!

**logInOutTest - 3rd iteration log:**
*- start login status check
- { status : "unknown" }
- start log IN
- Login Error: There is an error logging you into this application. Please try again later*

Although the status changed to unknown after log out I can't log in successfully again until I remove DemoApp from app logged in with facebook.

Additionally in Facebook I have those options:
*Login from devices - yes; Client OAuth Login - yes; Web OAuth Login - yes; Embedded Browser OAuth Login - yes; Force Web OAuth Reauthentication - no; Your app is currently live and available to the public - yes;* **App is not submitted, so I don't have the key to sign my apk**

I believe, Android platform settings are set properly with the right key hashed generated on mac (so no windows problem with ssl), asked me for my password, while generating.

I think I saw a post where facebook sdk has some extended options in the log out process, that can force the log out, but I didn't see a possibility to change them in both facebook plugins for phonegap

Comment: _“Seems like I successfully logged out, but DemoApp is still in Apps Logged in with Facebook”_ – Apps Logged in with Facebook is not a “live view” of what apps you are _currently_ logged into, but a list of _all_ apps you _ever_ logged in to. Logging out of your app doesn’t remove it from that list, simply because it is not supposed to do that.

Comment: Well, perhaps you're absolutely right, but than why I'm receiving an error while trying to log in again ?

Comment: Hmm, it seems like this is a new issue. Lots of people complaining lately. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/297086380683342/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was solved on the facebook page in the following thread

[problem with facebook login from android phone](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/297086380683342/)

In short key hash was invalid. Curious enough if you remove the app from your profile , it's working one time than fail every other. That's behavior that many people observed, including me. You can find more info in the thread.

Don't follow facebook instructions to generate hash key on their page. They are not working good enough or at least you can end with a wrong key, even if you follow them exactly!!!!

Here is a working way to do so:

[Generate Key Hash for Facebook for Android platform](https://software.intel.com/en-us/xdk/articles/facebook-android-keyhash)

All credits goes to Andrea Palmate.